# I can't remember the name of this mean/delta based transform

Tags: compression, transform

I once saw a transformation (a cousin of RLE, delta encoding, and other number based, 1D lossless transformation meant to help the Huffman compression) which was based on a recursive mean / delta operations.

example:

```
[3, 5] -> [4, +1]
```

where

```
4 = (3+5)/2 # the average value

4 - 1 = 3 = # the delta reconstruction
4 + 1 = 5
```

And the process was applied recursively... Maybe something like :

```
[3, 5, 4, 6] -> [4, +1, 5, +1] -> [4, 5, +1, +1] -> [4.5, +0.5, 1, +0] etc.
```

But I can't remember how, since I lost its name, hence I can't google it. Does it ring a bell to someone ?

Answer (score 0):

It's **mid / side encoding**. Usually audio compressors use it to increase compression ratio for stereo audio. For example, Monkey's Audio compressor use it as pointed out in its documentation: http://www.monkeysaudio.com/theory.html

Comment: interesting paper, but not exactly what as was looking for... No recursive trasnformation here, we have a standard joint stereo... (o_o;) I hate google for the fact we can not search for "the page I already stumbled upon yesterday !" (^o^)